# PHP - Send table row data to email where email address is a row data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email, pdo

I'm currently working on a ticketing system. and i have a problem on the function of the button. The button has two function, one is to send the table row data to another table, and second is to send an email to the user to notify that the ticket has been done. The address or the receiver of the email is also taken from the table row. The code for sending table row to another table is working but the code for sending the table row data to an email is not working at all. Can anyone help me solve this problem please?

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';

$id = null;

if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}
if ( null==$id ) {
    header("Location: closed.php");
}else{

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sqlii = "UPDATE tickets SET ticketStatus='DONE'  WHERE ticketId = ?";
    $qii = $pdo->prepare($sqlii);
    $qii->execute(array($id));
    Database::disconnect();

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO closedtickets SELECT * FROM tickets where ticketId = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    Database::disconnect();

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sqliii = "DELETE FROM tickets  WHERE ticketId = ?";
    $qi = $pdo->prepare($sqliii);
    $qi->execute(array($id));
    Database::disconnect(); 

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sqliii = "SELECT * FROM closedtickets  WHERE ticketId = ?";
    $qi = $pdo->prepare($sqliii);
    $qi->execute(array($id));
    Database::disconnect(); 
} 

/* The php script below is not working
// include phpmailer class */

require_once 'phpmailer.php';
/* creates object */
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM closedtickets WHERE ticketId = ?'; 
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

        $full_name  = ($_SESSION['adminName']);
        $email      = "email@email.com.ph";
        $admin = "admin@admin.com.ph";
        $ticketRefNum = $row['ticketRefNum'];
        $ticketDate = $row['ticketDate'];
        $ticketSubject = $row['ticketSubject'];
        $ticketReceiver = $row['ticketReceiver'];
        $ticketEmail = $row['ticketEmail'];
        $ticketStatus = $row['ticketStatus'];
        $text_message    = "From: IT Service Desk <br /> Ticket Date: $ticketDate 
        <br /> To: $ticketReceiver <br /> Subject: [Reference Number: 
        $ticketRefNum] $ticketSubject <br /> Ticket Status: $ticketStatus <br /> 
        <br /> <br /> Hi $ticketReceiver, your ticket about $subject has already 
        been done by the IT.";         

        /* email content */
        $message  = "$text_message";
    }
    Database::disconnect(); 

    /* SMTP Set up */
    try {
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.smtp.com";      
        $mail->Port       = 465;             
        $mail->AddAddress($ticketEmail);
        $mail->Username   ="email@email.com";  
        $mail->Password   ="password";            
        $mail->SetFrom($email,"Ticket");
        $mail->AddReplyTo($admin,"Ticket");
        $mail->Subject    = $ticketSubject;
        $mail->Body     = $message;
        $mail->AltBody    = $message;

        if($mail->Send()) {

          $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
              Hi,<br /> ".$full_name." mail was successfully sent to ".$email." 
      go and check, cheers :)
              </div>";
        }
    }
    catch(phpmailerException $ex) {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>".$ex->errorMessage()."</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You say not working - is it erroring at all? How is it not working

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Why are you connecting and disconnecting from the database around ever database access. The connection process is slow, and in this case unnecessary to do all over the place

Comment: Why are you `foreach`'ing over a resultset that should contain only one results?

Comment: Probably worth changing `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;`  to `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;` for more debugging

Comment: Why do you execute a SELECT query as the final thing in your table update set, and then totally ingore the result from that query, and then do it all again in your email phase.

Comment: Is this a real url `$mail->Host = "smtp.smtp.com";` it looks a little odd to me

Comment: Not sure if PHPMailer would error without debug on but are these real email addresses that you own? `"admin@admin.com.ph"` and `"email@email.com.ph"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly there's not showing any errors. I don't know what to use. Foreach was the loop I used in one of my script. I just tried it and hoping for it to work.

Comment: @RiggsFolly smtp.smtp.com was only a sample. I actually used smtp.gmail.com

Comment: @Matt that was not really the address on my script. Just an example